# A python-1.x tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

While Python 2 and 3 are by far the most popular versions of Python, there still should be a [python-1.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-1.x) tag to cover questions that are specifically related to Python 1.

Comment: If, after all this time, no one has needed a Python 1 version-specific tag, it seems rather unlikely that they will need one now. Do you have any examples of questions that need such a tag? We cannot create tags in the abstract, anyway; they must be applied to questions.

Comment: I last used Python 1.x in 2000. *No one* is asking questions about Python 1.x today, 20 years after Python 2 became common-place. Tags are based on *demand*, so if there are enough questions to warrant a separate dedicated tag to help with filtering. Without Python 1.x questions, there is no need to create a tag.

Comment: Just showing of your age @MartijnPieters ?

Comment: @rene: if I was trying to do that, I'd be talking about [the first computer I owned](https://www.msx.org/wiki/Toshiba_HX-10AA) :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters so you also started on an MSX .... there is hope for me .... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Let's flip this on its head.

When you author a question which deals with Python 1.x and requires an answer with Python 1.x, we can then elect to create a tag for it.  Until then, we're just creating unnecessary metadata for little actual practical use.